# Saving a numpy array in a C structure

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes

I am passing numpy arrays to C code using ctypes. I would like to keep that information in a C structure. I have the following code in C:

my_file.h

```c
typedef struct container
{
    int nb_rows;
    int nb_cols;
    double ** data;
};
void save_d2_double(int nb_rows, int nb_cols, double *data[nb_cols]);
void print_container();
```

my_file.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_file.h"    

struct container c;

void save_d2_double(int nb_rows, int nb_cols, double * data[nb_cols] ){
    c.nb_rows = nb_rows;
    c.nb_cols = nb_cols;
    c.data = data;
}

void print_container(){
   printf("\n");
   printf("%d\t%d", c.nb_rows, c.nb_cols);
   for(int i = 0; i < c.nb_rows; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < c.nb_cols; j++){
           printf("%f\t", c.data[i][j]); \\ Error here
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

And the following in python:

my_file.py

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct
import ctypes

LIBC = ctypes.CDLL("my_file.so")
array_2d_double = npct.ndpointer(dtype=np.double, ndim=2)
LIBC.save_d2_double.restype = None
LIBC.save_d2_double.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, array_2d_double]
LIBC.print_container.restype = None
LIBC.print_container.argtypes = []

# The shape of this array vary in the end application.
x_2d_d = np.array([[1.,2.,3.,10.],[4.,5.,6.,11.],[7.,8.,9.,12.]], dtype=np.float64)

shape = x_2d_d.shape
LIBC.save_d2_double(shape[0], shape[1], x_2d_d)
LIBC.print_container()
```

When I want to access `c.data` I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I suspect that the problem is in the declaration of `double ** data;` however, since C doesn't know in advance the dimensions of the numpy array, I don't know how to declare this filed.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @ Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica, You helped me out with questinos about ctypes before. Do you have suggestions for this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: `double *data[nb_cols]` is an array of pointers, or equivalently a double pointer, but that's not what Python is passing. Python is passing a 2D array, or equivalently a pointer to an array, so your function should take `double (*data)[nb_cols]` instead.

Second problem: C doesn't let you store a pointer to a VLA in a struct. You tried to use a double pointer instead, but a double pointer isn't compatible with a pointer to an array. However, there is a solution: since arrays are contiguous, you can instead treat the pointer as if it were just a pointer to the first element, and then cast it to a pointer to a VLA in the function where you use it (or manually convert the indices instead).

my_file.h:

```c
struct container
{
    int nb_rows;
    int nb_cols;
    double *data;
};
void save_d2_double(int nb_rows, int nb_cols, double *data); /* or double (*data)[nb_cols] */
void print_container(void);
```

my_file.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_file.h"    

struct container c;

void save_d2_double(int nb_rows, int nb_cols, double *data) { /* or double (*data)[nb_cols] */
    c.nb_rows = nb_rows;
    c.nb_cols = nb_cols;
    c.data = data;
}

void print_container(void) {
   double (*data)[c.nb_cols] = (double (*)[c.nb_cols])c.data; /* optional; see below */
   printf("\n");
   printf("%d\t%d", c.nb_rows, c.nb_cols);
   for(int i = 0; i < c.nb_rows; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < c.nb_cols; j++) {
           printf("%f\t", data[i][j]); /* or c.data[i * c.nb_cols + j] */
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Dear @Joseph Sible, you are a life saver.  What should I read to learn all these nuances?

Comment: @mm_ I just picked this up over time and can't really point to a single source where I learned it.

Comment: @ Joseph Sible, could you unpack  `double (*data)[c.nb_cols] = (double (*)[c.nb_cols])c.data;` please? How would you do it for a 3 dim or 4 dim array?

Comment: @mm_ There should be a separate `[]` for every dimension but the first. So something like `double (*data)[c.nb_cols][c.nb_third_dimension_size][c.nb_fourth_dimension_size]`

Comment: @ Joseph Sible, So for 4 dimensions it would be `double (*data)[nb_2][nb_3][nb_4] = (double (*)[nb_2][nb_3][nb_4] )c.data`. But this does not work for me. Is the second expression like casting a type?

Comment: @mm_ You should post a new question for that with all of your code and the exact problem details.